# The metric in Example $1.1-6$ would not be suitable in the present case. (Why? Can you explain?)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

**1.1-6** Sequence space $l^{\infty} .$ This example and the next one give a first impression of how surprisingly general the concept of a metric space is.

As a set $X$ we take the set of all bounded sequences of complex numbers; that is, every element of $X$ is a complex sequence
$$
x=\left(\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, \cdots\right) \quad \text { briefly } \quad x=\left(\xi_{j}\right)
$$
such that for all $j=1,2, \cdots$ we have
$$
\left|\xi_{j}\right| \leqq c_{x}
$$
where $c_{x}$ is a real number which may depend on $x$, but does not depend on $j$. We choose the metric defined by

(9)
$$
d(x, y)=\sup _{j \in \mathbf{N}}\left|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}\right|
$$
where $y=\left(\eta_{j}\right) \in X$ and $\mathbf{N}=\{1,2, \cdots\}$, and sup denotes the supremum (least upper bound). $.^{5}$ The metric space thus obtained is generally denoted by $l^{\infty}$. (This somewhat strange notation will be motivated by $1.2-3$ in the next section.) $l^{\infty}$ is a sequence space because each element of $X($ each point of $X)$ is a sequence.

**1.2-1** Sequence space s. This space consists of the set of all (bounded or unbounded) sequences of complex numbers and the metric $d$ defined by
$$
d(x, y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{j}} \frac{\left|\xi_{j}-\eta_{i}\right|}{1+\left|\xi_{j}-\eta_{j}\right|}
$$
where $x=\left(\xi_{j}\right)$ and $y=\left(\eta_{j}\right)$. **Note that the metric in Example $1.1-6$ would not be suitable in the present case. (Why?)**

**My Question is:** Note that the metric in Example $1.1-6$ would not be suitable in the present case. (Why? Can you explain?)

Comment: Well, what would the sup mean in that case?  That is, why would the sup have to exist?

Comment: @lulu I think i understand...  In this case we have the sum over j so ıf supremum exist in the case, the case would be meaningless, right?

Comment: I don't understand.  You asked why the first metric did not apply to the second case.  That's because the sup doesn't need to exist in the second case (just try $x=\{0,0,0,0,\cdots\}$ and $y=\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots\}$ for instance).  There is no sum involved.

Comment: For the second metric, you need to argue that the metric actually exists (not difficult) and, of course, you need to argue that it satisfies the axioms of a metric (maybe less straight forward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metric on $s$ is well-defined for **all** real-valued sequences: we never divide by $0$ in the fraction, $0 \le\frac{|xi_j-\eta_j|}{1+|xi_j - \eta_j|} \le 1 $ for all $j$ so that the sum is dominated by the geometric series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^j}$ which has sum $1$. So the value is always a finite real. The sup as used in $\ell^\infty$ is only guaranteed to be finite if the sequences themselves are bounded (so a limitation on the elements), so their difference is bounded too.